# How to run react-native app with offline bundle in real device?

Tags: ios, react-native

I have wrote some code, and things run well on simulator.
And I checked the official document on how to run on device. This is what I have done:

1,comment this line in AppDelegate.m

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

2,uncomment:

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

And they say

> 'The static bundle is automatically generated by the "Bundle React Native code and images" build step when running the project on an actual device'

I clicked 'run', and red screen appeared:'connect refused'.
To ensure the main.jsbundle IS in the project, I manually generate it with the *curl* command.
But the error still there:

```
Websocket connection failed with error ErrorDomain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 'connection refused'
```

Hours in googling, but got no help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the sheme to *Release*.
That works.

But what still confusing is why *debug* not work..

Comment: When you change the scheme to release, it's going to compile whole jscode  and make it available in main bundle. So that's how it works on offline. In Debug, it will go to localhost:8081, that's why it's not working. Even in debug, it's possible if you compile ur jscode and add to your project.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the scheme to release, it's going to compile whole `jscode` and make it available in **main** bundle. So that's how it works on offline. In Debug, it will go to `localhost:8081`, because in your main bundle there won't be compiled JSCode. that's why it's not working. Even in debug, it's possible if you compile ur jscode and add to your project.

Answer (score 0):

If using a physical iOS device, ensure that your Macbook and device are on the same wifi network as well as plugged in with a lightning to USB cable.
[See docs for more info](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device)